# undefined method `has_key?'

Tags: ruby

There can be an issue with my code rather than the fact that I'm attempting to use an undefined method. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
           dest_ip = 2.2.2.2
           dest_port = 4444
           def check_db(ip,port)
               #is this target recorded?
                targets = YAML.load_file('targets.yml')
                if (targets[ip] || {}).include? port
                    puts "\nThis target exists already!!\n"
                else
                    puts "\nThis target does NOT exist!!\n"
                end
           end
           check_db(dest_ip,dest_port)
```

My `targets.yml` file looks like this

```
            69.39.239.151:
            - 7777
            - 8677
            69.39.239.75:
            - 9677
            - 9377
            209.15.212.147:
            - 8477
            - 7777
            104.156.244.109:
            1.1.1.1: 8888
            2.2.2.2: 4444
```

I'm getting this error:

```
$ ruby test.rb
test.rb:9:in `<main>': undefined method `has_key?' for 4444:Fixnum (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of problems, mostly that you're YML file isn't formatted correctly. `104.156.244.109:` needs to have a value. `1.1.1.1` and `2.2.2.2` need to have arrays as their value not numeric values.  Change your YML file to this (I made up a value for `104.156.224.109` and you should be okay:

```
69.39.239.151:
  - 7777
  - 8677
69.39.239.75:
  - 9677
  - 9377
209.15.212.147:
  - 8477
  - 7777
104.156.244.109:
  - 9999
1.1.1.1:
  - 8888
2.2.2.2:
  - 4444
```

The error you're getting is because `target['2.2.2.2']` is returning literally `4444` which is a Fixnum which doesn't respond to `include?`. Or in other words you're code expecting an array to be returned and you're returning a single integer.

Also, at least for me, I had to quote '2.2.2.2' in the ruby code.